# I cannot get my Angular app running locally

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I cannot get my angular application to run locally. I am getting an error that my interview.js and angular.js are not being found. Also, angular is not defined in the interview.js file when I open it from the dev console.

Here is my directory structure:

```
mock
public
    index.html
src
    services
    interview.js
vendor
    angular.js
```

Here is my index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Interview Practice</title>
  <meta name="description" content="">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script src="../vendor/angular.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="interviewapp">
  hello world!

  <script src="../src/interview.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my interview.js

```
angular.module("interviewapp", []);
console.log("does this work");
```

I'm using http-server to start the application.

```
Starting up http-server, serving ./public
Available on:
  http://10.66.87.184:8080
  http://192.168.56.1:8080
  http://127.0.0.1:8080
```

Going to localhost, or any of the https listed there, this is the error I get:

```
http://10.66.87.184:8080/vendor/angular.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
http://10.66.87.184:8080/src/interview.js Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

How do I fix this so that my app runs?

Comment: Move `src` and `vendor` directories into `public` directory and remove the `..` from the start of your paths to files e.g. change `src="../src/interview.js"` to `src="/src/interview.js"`

Comment: I linked a cdn for angular, and did what you said for the src folder. Could you tell me why that worked?

Comment: Added an answer for you with explanation

Answer (score 2):

As stated in the comment:

Move `src` and `vendor` directories into `public` directory and remove the .. from the start of your paths to files e.g. change `src="../src/interview.js"` to `src="/src/interview.js"`

This works because your server is using `public` as the root folder, therefore it cannot see the other folders you're trying to access. By moving them in to `public` folder, it can then access them.

Answer (score 0):

change your project structure to look like this:

```
mock
public
    index.html
    src
    vendor
```

also change this:

```
<script src="../vendor/angular.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

to this:

```
<script src="/vendor/angular.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

and this:

```
<script src="../src/interview.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

to this

```
<script src="/src/interview.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

So all of your javascripts should be in your public directory.  Also never use relative paths for include tags. Anything in public should be accessible since it is the root folder.

Answer (score 0):

Your server is serving `public` folder. So anything within that folder can be accessed via your host name. But you have kept `src` and `vendor` out side of `public`, hence they are not served through your server. In order to access them put them in `public` folder and remove the `..` before your js reference.